# Bounding $t \ln(1 +t)$ for $t > 0$

Tags: logarithms, upper-lower-bounds

How would you derive the following bound?
$$t\ln(1+t) \geq 2t - 2\ln(1+t)\qquad \text{for $t>0$.}$$
I have only been able to derive 
$$t\ln(1+t) \geq t - \ln(1+t)\qquad \text{for $t>0$.}$$

Comment: Hint: If $f(0)\geq 0$ and $f'(x)\geq 0$ for $x\geq 0$ then $f(x)\geq 0$ for $x\geq 0$

Comment: My bad. I forgot a 2. Corrected now.

Comment: Shall I open a new question instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider the function
$$f(t)=\log(1+t)-\frac{2t}{t+2}$$ and $$t>0$$ and we get $f(0)=0$ so we have 
$$f'(t)=\frac{t-1}{(1+t)^2}$$ so $f'(t)>0$ if $t>1$

Answer (score 1):

The inequality
$$t\ln(1+t) ≥ 2t - \ln(1+t)$$
does NOT hold for $t\geq 0$. Take $t=e-1>0$, then
$$e-1=(e-1)\ln(e)\geq  2(e-1) - \ln(e)=2e-3\implies 2\geq e$$
which is false!
On the other hand, by letting
$$f(t)=t\ln(1+t) -2t + 2\ln(1+t)$$
we have that
$$f'(t)=\ln(1+t)+\frac{t}{1+t}-2+\frac{2}{1+t}=\frac{(1+t)\ln(1+t)-t}{1+t}$$
which is non-negative by your second bound (the one that you proved!). Hence $f$ is increasing in $[0,+\infty)$ and $f(t)\geq f(0)=0$ implies that for $t\geq 0$, 
$$t\ln(1+t) ≥ 2t - 2\ln(1+t).$$

Comment: My bad. I forgot a 2. Corrected now.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion in the beginning. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @mexmex May I know why you changed your mind about my answer? BTW the other one is not correct.